# Python - plot from txt file, skipping lines

Tags: python, file, plot

I have a problem with my script. I have (blabla.)txt file, for example:

```
blablaba bla
dsadsadsa
dsadsadsa
50 2323
60 2839
70 9832
80 0000
.....
....
...
```

and script I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("blabla.txt") as f:
    for line in xrange(3):
        next(f)
    for line in f:

      data = f.read()

      data = data.split('\n')

      x = [row.split()[0] for row in data]
      y = [row.split()[1] for row in data]

      index = [i for i,val in enumerate(x)]

      fig = plt.figure()
      ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
      ax1.set_title("graph")    
      ax1.set_xlabel('time')
      ax1.set_ylabel('distance')
      ax1.set_xticklabels(x)
      ax1.plot(index ,y, c='r', label='distance1')
      leg = ax1.legend()
      plt.locator_params(nbins=len(index)-1)
      plt.show()
```

The first question is: Is it true (syntax in the script) when I want to skip (because of the graph) the first three lines in the txt file?

The second: After runscript it says:

```
data = f.read()
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data.
```

What is the problem, its because of size?
(txt file has about 600 000 lines)

Thanks for all the help....Funstorm60

Comment: Start by fixing you indentation.

Comment: Then read a basic tutorial about reading files in Python. The error is quite sensible, if you understand the conceptual incompatibility between `for line in file:` and `file.read()`. One reads the file line-by-line, the other one as a block. You should pick one and design your code around that, not try to mix and match.

Comment: And 600,000 lines is not a problem on any reasonably modern machine. Even if you have a weird 4-byte encoding and an average of 64 characters per line, that's still only ~150MiB out of the GiBs of RAM you probably have.

Comment: @MadPhysicist mentioned the issue:  "For every line in f, read all of f into variable data." That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
with open("<fname>.txt", 'r') as datafile:
    __data = datafile.readlines()[3:]

data = [[float(value) for value in line.split()] for line in __data]
```

This will give you a 2D array of your data - although it doesn't include the index information that you've included in your question.

EDIT: Sorry I missed the call to `.split()`

EDIT: As an example

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
6 5 4 3
```

will give the output:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0]]
```

Comment: That does not explain what is actually wrong with OP's version. Also, you don't need `__data = datafile.readlines()`: you can replace `__data` with `datafile` in the list comprehension, if you call `next` on it three times first. That will save you *a lot* of memory.

Comment: Absolutely - I was just offering an example of a simple way to read data as these types of answers were helpful for me when I was learning.